# Loop along variable names and stacking them

Tags: r, loops

I have several raster layers that are named "SPI1, SPI2,SPI3,SPI4... SPI396".

I want to stack them al together but I don't know how to loop along the names, the basic idea is something like this:

```
stack(SPI1, SPI2, SPI3, SPI4... SPI396)
```

I thought on something like :

```
for (i in 1:396){
stack(SPIi)
}
```

But of course I need to iterate along that "i". Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe `stack(mget(paste0("SPI", 1:396)))`? This would not need a loop.

Comment: `eapply(.GlobalEnv, identity)` turn it into list. `stack` on it should work. But true question is where this 296 objects came from?

Comment: Rui Barradas' comment work out perfect, thank you.